# How to suppress a 'missing termination character' warning in cpp?

Tags: c-preprocessor, ansi-c, picoblaze

I'm trying to use cpp (ANSI-C preprocessor) to preprocess some non ANSI-C files.

These files contain assembly instruction in PicoBlaze syntax. PicoBlaze uses `'d` to annotate the literal's radix. I would like to preprocess my files with cpp.

I get several:

```
<stdin>:228:163: warning: missing terminating ' character [enabled by default]
<stdin>:257:98: warning: missing terminating ' character [enabled by default]
...
```

warnings. How can I disable termination character checks for `'` (or all characters) in cpp?

Here is my command line call:

```
cpp.exe -E main_Page0.psm
```

Comment: I'm not posting as an answer since I don't know this is authoritative, but you're specifically attempting to use an ANSI-C compliant preprocessor to handle non-ANSI compliant files... I do not believe that there is an option to do what you are trying to do.  This may be a perfect job for a tool like sed.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer If I understood the warning correctly, cpp is missing the closing `'` character after `ADD Reg0, 01'd`. Why does the preprocessor check lines for such character? This shouldn't be a concern for a pre processor ...

Comment: @paebbels: The preprocessor should not expand macro names inside quoted strings or character literals, so it must understand quoting syntaxes. (eg. even if `d` were a macro, `'d'` is still the character literal `'d'`. And sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution by myself, but I'm still open for other suggestions.

**Solution 1)**
`-w` disables all warnings -> dissatisfying

> Suppress all warnings, including those which GNU CPP issues by default.
>   [GCC Manual (v4.9.2) -> page 158](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc.pdf#page=172)

**Solution 2)**
`-x assembler-with-cpp` sets cpp's source language to assembly.
Default language is ANSI-C, if the file extension is unknown (equals `-x c`).

> Specify the source language: C, C++, Objective-C, or assembly. This has nothing to do with standards conformance or extensions; it merely selects which
>   base syntax to expect. If you give none of these options, cpp will deduce the
>   language from the extension of the source file: ‘.c’, ‘.cc’, ‘.m’, or ‘.S’. Some
>   other common extensions for C++ and assembly are also recognized. If cpp does
>   not recognize the extension, it will treat the file as C; this is the most generic mode.
>   [GCC Manual (v4.9.2) -> page 160](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc.pdf#page=174)

Comment: #2 works well when filtering HTML with CPP.  Thanks!